# Building dynamic UI using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to JavaFx and trying to build the following screen with three StackPane that can dynamicall grow and shrink the width and height depending on the window size. I tried different ways but was not able to achieve this. I also tried using AnchorPane constraints. here is the image of what i'm trying to achieve and corresponding FXML. here is are the constraints I'm looking between these panes

- Left Pane to have a max width (300px) and min 150
- distance between left and right(2) stack panes should remain constant
- distance between right top and bottom stack panes should remain constant
- left top stack pane to have max height of 250px

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"
    minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="437.0"
    prefWidth="736.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <StackPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="405.0"
            prefWidth="223.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;"
            AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="12.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="15.0"
            AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0">
            <effect>
                <DropShadow />
            </effect>
        </StackPane>
        <StackPane layoutX="251.0" layoutY="21.0" prefHeight="119.0"
            prefWidth="470.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff;"
            AnchorPane.leftAnchor="251.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0"
            AnchorPane.topAnchor="21.0">
            <effect>
                <DropShadow />
            </effect>
        </StackPane>
        <StackPane layoutX="251.0" layoutY="150.0"
            prefHeight="269.0" prefWidth="470.0"
            style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="13.0"
            AnchorPane.leftAnchor="251.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0">
            <effect>
                <DropShadow />
            </effect>
        </StackPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[image]

Comment: How do you want the 3 stack panes to behave when window size changes ?

Comment: - Left Pane to have a max width (300px) and min 150
- distance between left and right(2) stack panes should remain constant
- distance between right top and bottom stack panes should remain constant
- left top stack pane to have max height of 250px

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the essential info to it. _"distance between left and right(2) stack panes should remain constant - distance between right top and bottom stack panes should remain constant_" this is not clear to me.

Comment: @c0der thanks for pointing. added those details to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help. I found a way to do it using the GridPane(root pane), VBox, Anchor and stack panes . . Here is the fxml for that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <content>
      <GridPane hgap="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="700.0" minWidth="700.0" style="-fx-border-width: 20px; -fx-border-color: white;">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="347.79999389648435" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="139.0000061035156" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="309.79999389648435" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="180.00003662109373" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="204.79996337890628" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="204.79996337890628" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <VBox prefHeight="479.0" prefWidth="274.0" spacing="10.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue; -fx-border-insets: 10;" GridPane.rowSpan="2147483647">
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow />
               </effect>
            </VBox>
            <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="10.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2147483647" GridPane.rowSpan="2147483647">
               <children>
                  <AnchorPane prefHeight="178.0" prefWidth="547.0" style="-fx-background-color: green;">
                     <effect>
                        <DropShadow />
                     </effect>
                  </AnchorPane>
                  <StackPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="403.0" prefWidth="547.0" style="-fx-background-color: yellow;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <effect>
                        <DropShadow />
                     </effect>
                  </StackPane>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

One I added this this my borderpane here is how it looked

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You just needed to set some max-widths and max-heights.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <StackPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="27.0" maxWidth="400.0" prefHeight="405.0" prefWidth="223.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="12.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
            <effect>
                <DropShadow />
            </effect>
            <HBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
            </HBox.margin>
        </StackPane>
        <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
            <children>
                <StackPane layoutX="251.0" layoutY="21.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="119.0" prefWidth="470.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="251.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="21.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <effect>
                        <DropShadow />
                    </effect>
                    <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                    </VBox.margin>
                </StackPane>
                <StackPane layoutX="251.0" layoutY="150.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="269.0" prefWidth="470.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="13.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="251.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <effect>
                        <DropShadow />
                    </effect>
                    <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                    </VBox.margin>
                </StackPane>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</HBox>
```

[image]

[image]

**You might need to play with the max-width of the left-panel**

Comment: Thanks for the quick update.. i had the max height and width but did not work as expected. I have a different structure inside these panes. I will work and see if i have fit those in these. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yea, your current structure will not work. Your structure needs to mirror this answer.